# Is there an JetBrains IDE API for socket configuration port?

Tags: java, python, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am using a lot of WebStorm projects at once. I have made Python GUI to basic scripts to these projects, and I run WebStorm for any of these by running `webstrom .` inside of each.

I want to know which of them is actually opened, cause when I tried to use python 'psutil' and I only findout java child process of first opened project rest of them is probably some kind of 'extra window' for first opened.

So in `/usr/local/bin/webstorm.sh` I find out that this script is asking to some port if WebStorm is opened and trying to create next instance if it actually is:

```
CONFIG_PATH = u'/home/pawel/.WebStorm2019.1/config'
SYSTEM_PATH = u'/home/pawel/.WebStorm2019.1/system'

import socket
import struct
import sys
import time

def try_activate_instance(args):
    port_path = os.path.join(CONFIG_PATH, 'port')
    token_path = os.path.join(SYSTEM_PATH, 'token')
    if not (os.path.exists(port_path) and os.path.exists(token_path)):
        return False

    try:
        with open(port_path) as pf:
            port = int(pf.read())
        with open(token_path) as tf:
            token = tf.read()
    except (ValueError):
        return False

    s = socket.socket()
    s.settimeout(0.3)
    try:
        s.connect(('127.0.0.1', port))
    except (socket.error, IOError):
        return False

    found = False
    while True:
        try:
            path_len = struct.unpack('>h', s.recv(2))[0]
            path = s.recv(path_len).decode('utf-8')
            if os.path.abspath(path) == os.path.abspath(CONFIG_PATH):
                found = True
                break
        except (socket.error, IOError):
            return False

    print(found)
    if found:
        cmd = 'activate ' + token + '\0' + os.getcwd() + '\0' + '\0'.join(args)
        if sys.version_info[0] >= 3: cmd = cmd.encode('utf-8')
        encoded = struct.pack('>h', len(cmd)) + cmd
        s.send(encoded)
        time.sleep(0.5)  # don't close the socket immediately
        return True

    return False


try_activate_instance([])
```

Are there any other commands than `activate [token]` or JetBrains wiki about them like:

- 'isactive [token] [project_name]' - returns if project from this directory is opened
- 'target [token] [project_name]' - move window of project on top in linux